# How to append current date to property file value every day in Unix?

Tags: bash, properties, cron

I've got a property file which is read several times per day by an external application in order to process some files. One of the properties tells the app where to store the processed files. Application runs on Linux.

```
success_path=/u02/oapp/success
```

The problem is that every day several files are thrown in that path and after several months, I would have thousands of files in this plane folder.

Question: How can I append the current date to this property file so it would look like:

```
success_path=/u02/oapp/success/dd-MMM-yyyy
```

This would be updated every day at 12:00AM so for example today it would be

```
success_path=/u02/oapp/success/28-JAN-2017
```

The file is `/u02/oapp/configuration/oapp.properties`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is modifying the property file the only way to achieve this?  Using a config file as some kind of clock seems a bit of a hack, although what you want to to is otherwise not very difficult.

Comment: The other way is to modify the code which was written by ex-vendor and I don't want to find out how many things will break on me changing it as I have little time to spend on this. It is not an actual requirement, it will only make my life easier. How can I achieve this with a crontab job?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending current date to the property, add additional logic to the code that stores the processed files so that:

- it takes the base directory from the property file (`success_path` in your case)
- it creates a year/month/day directory to store the files

Something like:

```
/u02/oapp/success/year/month/day (as in `/u02/oapp/success/2017/01/01`)
or
/u02/oapp/success/yearmonth/day  (as in `/u02/oapp/success/201701/01`)
or
/u02/oapp/success/yearmonthday   (as in `/u02/oapp/success/20170101`)
```

If you don't have the capability to change the app's behavior, you might need to write a cron job that periodically moves the files external to the app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'd like to avoid touching the code. It is just a jenga tower and I wouldn't be surprise changing this would break a lot of other stuff. So, any idea how to do it with a cron job?

Answer (score 0):

```
jq -Rr 'select(startswith("success_path="))="success_path=/u02/oapp/success/"+(now|strflocaltime("%d-%b-%Y")|ascii_upcase)' /u02/oapp/configuration/oapp.properties | sponge /u02/oapp/configuration/oapp.properties
```